# Derby equivalent of Oracle CONNECT BY / START WITH

Tags: sql, oracle, derby

I'm looking for a way to port an Oracle query that uses START WITH / CONNECT BY to Derby. Suggestions?

Comment: Based on the [info here](http://old.nabble.com/Recursive-query-on-common-table-td25819772.html), Derby doesn't currently have any recursive functionality.  SQL-99 saw the recursive CTE (WITH clause) implemented as the defacto hierarchical/recursive SQL query syntax.

Comment: The only embedded Java DB engine I know that supports recursive CTE is H2